# Why does g++ 4.x allows implicit conversion of nullptr to another types when passed as parameter but > 5.x dont?

Tags: c++11, gcc, g++, nullptr

My understanding is that, nullptr could not be converted implicitly to another types. But later I "found" that it could be converted to bool.
The issue is, I can see it being converted to bool on GCC 4.x, but it complains on GCC > 5.X

```
#include <iostream>
bool f(bool a){
    return !a;
}
// Type your code here, or load an example.
int main() {
    return f(nullptr);
}
```

On >5.x I get

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':

<source>:7:21: error: converting to 'bool' from 'std::nullptr_t' requires direct-initialization [-fpermissive]
     return f(nullptr);

             ^

<source>:2:6: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'bool f(bool)'
 bool f(bool a){

      ^
Compiler returned: 1
```

I couldn't find anything on the release notes of GCC 5.X that would explain that.

Can be observed here:
https://godbolt.org/g/1Uc2nM

Can someone explain why there is a difference between versions and what rule is applied here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule can be found in C++17 [conv.bool]/1:

> For direct-initialization, a prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t` can
>   be converted to a prvalue of type `bool`; the resulting value is false.

Initialization of function parameters is *copy-initialization* , not *direct-initialization*. If you are not familiar with this topic; initialization contexts in C++ can be divided into these two classes, and there are some operations that can only occur in direct-initialization.

The restriction to direct-initialization was added in C++14,  which could explain the difference between g++ versions.

I assume the purpose of this rule is to raise an error for the exact code you've written: a `bool` is expected and a null pointer constant was provided; testing a null pointer constant for boolean-ness is not very meaningful since it only has one state anyway.

Remember that `nullptr` is not a pointer; it's a thing that can be implicitly converted to a null pointer if the code explicitly requests such a conversion. The whole reason for adding it was to fix the hack of `0` being used as a null pointer constant, and inadvertently matching some other template or overload.

The code could be:

```
return f(static_cast<bool>(nullptr));
```

or perhaps you could add an overload of `f` that accepts `std::nullptr_t`.